# Entity Framework from database - calculate property from another table

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my database I have tables `Person` and `Work` that are connected with one `Person` to many `Work` with a foreign key `PersonId`.

These are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Work]
(
        [WorkId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [KollelStatusId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [Job] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Mascoret] [int] NULL,

        CONSTRAINT [PK_Work] 
           PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([WorkId] ASC)
                   WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                         IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                         ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Work] WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Work_Person] 
   FOREIGN KEY([PersonId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([PersonId])

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person]
(
        [PersonId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [FamilyId] [int] NULL,
        [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [DateOfBirth] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
        [TeudatZehut] [varchar](9) NULL,
        [Phone] [varchar](15) NULL,
        [Email] [varchar](100) NULL,
        [Issue] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,

        CONSTRAINT [PK_KupaPerson] 
           PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PersonId] ASC)
                   WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                         IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                         ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I need to show the persons in an ASP.NET MVC view. but instead of `PersonId`, I want to show the `Job` string.

How to do it with Entity Framework generated from database?

Thanks?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` is useful here.

Comment: Of course. I now. but how to do it in entity framework code, that for every Person, it will insert to not mapped property his jobs names?

Comment: I could by every person Constructor, to get his jobs, but it will create to many times access to DB.

Comment: (1) If one Person has many Joibs, which exactly Job are you going to show per Person? (2) It's not good to mix an **entity** with projection (select result)

Comment: If i would only show the first job, how i would do it? I also need to show works with the name of the person, not the personId. how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you got the personId in the value _personId you could do like this:

```
var listOfJobs = db.Work.Where(a=>a.PersonId == _personId).Select(a=>a.Job).ToList();
```

This will return a list of the jobs that person is linked to.

If you only got the name or any other value from the person model you could do something like this:

```
var listOfJobs = db.Work.Where(a=>a.Person.LastName == _lastName).Select(a=>a.Job).ToList();
```

This will return a list of the jobs that all persons with the LastName is equal to _lastName value.

If you want to get values from both tables you could JOIN the entities:

```
var listOfObjects = from w in db.Work
join p in db.Person on p.PersonId equals w.PersonId
where w.PersonId == _personId
select w.Job, p.FirstName;
```

If you want all persons jobs from the db, just remove the where statement from above like:

```
var listOfObjects = from w in db.Work
join p in db.Person on p.PersonId equals w.PersonId 
select w.Job, p.FirstName;
```

This will generate one query to fetch all persons jobs.

If you need more values from the models, just extend the select statement with more values like:

```
select w.Job, p.FirstName, p.LastName, w.WorkId, w.Mascoret
```

Comment: but then i need for every person to access database to get his jobs. If for example, i have 10000 persons, i will make one access to get all the persons, and another 10000 to get every one jobs. If i would use raw sql, not entity framework, i could get all the data in one query.

Comment: @ZagGol Just remove the Where statement in all above queries and you will get one query that returns all persons jobs. Updated my question aswell

Comment: now i see your join approach. it will only demand one access to database. but how i could put it into the model from database classes? maby i should also get in your join query the person id, and in loop, set every List<Job> property of person with the jobs we got from database?

Comment: @ZagGol You could just add more values to the select statement. I've updated the answers.